# How to get an external page's content on asp.net?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I need to get the contents of a page (which is just an image) like http://11.11.11.11/code.aspx?product=33 but only ip:22.22.22.22 has access to that file. Therefore I need to be able to do it from my pics.aspx file on another server like http://22.22.22.22/pics.aspx?code=33

So far I have this script below, which can get the `?code=33`. Now all I have to do is retrieve the contents of http://11.11.11.11/code.aspx?product=`subKeys(Counter2)`. I have worked with PHP in the past so I don't know what I'm doing with asp. if you could guide me a little on how to retrieve contents of another page via its url, it would be much appreciated :)

```
<%@ Page Language="vb" %>
<html>
   <head>
      <title>Showing QueryString values via the QueryString Collection in ASP.NET</title>
   </head>
<body>


<%
Dim Counter1, Counter2 As Integer
Dim Keys(), subKeys() As String
Dim MyQueryStringCollection As NameValueCollection

MyQueryStringCollection=Request.QueryString

Keys = MyQueryStringCollection.AllKeys
For Counter1 = 0 To Keys.GetUpperBound(0)
 subKeys = MyQueryStringCollection.GetValues(Counter1) ' Get all values under this key.
If Keys(Counter1)="code" Then
Response.Write("Counter is "& Keys(Counter1) & "<br>" & subKeys(Counter2))
End If
   subKeys = MyQueryStringCollection.GetValues(Counter1) ' Get all values under this key.
   For Counter2 = 0 To subKeys.GetUpperBound(0)
      ' Response.Write("Value " & CStr(Counter2) & ": " & subKeys(Counter2) & "<br>")
   Next Counter2
Next Counter1
%>


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: i'm looking for something like `include` for php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at the [WebRequest](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webrequest%28v=VS.100%29.aspx) and [WebResponse](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webresponse%28v=VS.100%29.aspx) classes.  They will allow you to request the contents of other pages.  It's then up to you how you want to display the response.

Hope that get's you on track.