# `include` statement for aspx?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I'm trying to include an external aspx page on my aspx (VB) page. If it were php i would have done it with a line of code like `<? include "http://www.google.com"; ?>` what would be the equivalent of include statement for aspx? Isn't there a VERY SIMPLE way of doing this?

Comment: for those who are wondering why I need this:  [click here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6610228/how-to-get-an-external-pages-content-on-asp-net)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't really understand why you need this.. But

1. If you need to have some another page on your page, you can use `iframes` for that.
2. If you create your custom control what would do HTTP request to required site output response as control HTML.

Comment: for those who are wondering why I need this:  [click here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6610228/how-to-get-an-external-pages-content-on-asp-net)

Comment: could you explain #2 a little please?

Comment: yeah.. custom controls are quite powerfull stuff in ASP.NET webforms. It's code + markup that you are able to apply behaviour that you want. You control could use WebClient class inside to make a request to any site, response coulde be rendered back on your side as HTML. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y6wb1a0e(v=vs.71).aspx

Answer (score 1):

In ASP.Net, you set up the page to include as a custom or user control, and add the control to the page. Includes don't really work well.

Answer (score 1):

It really depends what you are intending to do, if you are trying to get some shared user interface elements, then master pages, or user controls are what you are looking for

If you are trying to include common functionality, you can inherit this by inheriting from a base page which itself inherits from System.Web.UI.Page, and which contains the common code.